# NSMutableArray doesn't store any object

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablearray

My NSMutableArray doesn't store any object, either a String or a complex class. I tried it to allocate ind init and to init as an array. Both without success.

.m file:

```
@interface WorkCentersViewController()
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *selectedWorkCenters;
@end


@implementation WorkCentersViewController
@synthesize selectedWorkCenters;


-(id)init{

    self = [super init];

    if(self){


        //self.selectedWorkCenters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //doesn't work too
        self.selectedWorkCenters = [NSMutableArray array];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [selectedWorkCenters release];
    [super dealloc];
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){      
        ...
    }else{
        //select
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
        //add
        [self.selectedWorkCenters addObject:[self.workCenters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"Sel WC Count: %d", [self.selectedWorkCenters count]); //always 0
    }
}
```

Why is it not storing my object of WorkCenter? What I'm doing wrong?

BR,
mybecks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps that specific init method isn't being called?  Is this a UITableViewController?  Maybe you're initializing it with `initWithStyle:`?  I'd set a break point on the line where you init the array just to check.

Comment: I call it from the RootViewController: 
`- (void) insertNewWorkplace
{
    NSLog(@"Add new workplace");
    WorkCentersViewController *workCentersController = [[WorkCentersViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:workCentersController animated:YES];
    [workCentersController release];
}`
Yes it is a TableViewController. The init Method is called, I tested it with a Brreakpoint before.

Comment: Set a breakpoint or use NSLog in the init just to make sure.  Also I'd make certain that the object you are trying to add to the array isn't nil.

Comment: My Object is not null, I test it with NSLOg. My output of NSLog in viewDidLoad is ( ).

Answer (score 0):

[`-initWithNibName:bundle:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName%3abundle%3a) is `UIViewController`'s designated initializer, so any init code should show up in an override of that method. If this *is* a subclass of `UITableViewController`, Mark is correct that `initWithStyle` is a good place to put it.

Also, in general, `viewDidLoad`/`viewDidUnload` give you a good place to alloc/dealloc data structures that your view needs, but that can be recreated if needed.

Comment: I added my init code of the NSMutableArray to the viewDidLoad method. But won't works either with [[... alloc] init] and [NSMutableArray array]

Comment: `NSLog` both arrays (`workCenters` and `selected...`) and see what you find. Perhaps `workCenters` is nil?

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing your NSMutableArray in this way:

```
self.selectedWorkCenters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here are my ideas. In your init you are using:

```
// This one is wrong, you are [NSMutableArray array] returns a NSArray which cannot be 
// mutated so you cannot add objects to it. That is why it is not working.
//
self.selectedWorkCenters = [NSMutableArray array];

// This one is wrong because you have a leak here (Although it should work)
//
self.selectedWorkCenters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Try this:

```
selectedWorkCenters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

And place it in the **viewDidLoad** method. Hope it helps. Let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error.

In a other method I had the assignment

```
selectedWorkCenters = availableWorkCenters;
```

availableWorkCenters wasn't initialized - always 0x0 in the debugger screen.